# Xcode: Reloading a portion of controller with each view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am working on an IPhone app that, through viewDidLoad, makes a connection and pulls data into a table. I would like the controller, or at least the table, to reload every time the controller is displayed, even if someone just switched from one tab to another or closed and re-opened the app on this controller. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to find anything, it's also kind of a hard thing to search for. I have found discussions of when to put code in viewDidLoad but not another method that is run every them the controller displays.

Thanks,
Cheryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it by injecting code in only one place.

You can think of a workaround, like for example sending custom "reload request" notification from required parts of code:

1. `viewDidAppear:` in your view controller
2. `applicationDidBecomeActive:` (if table is presented)
3. `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` (if switched onto controller with the table)
4. `tabBar:didSelectItem:` (same as above)
5. etc.

In you view controller simply observe this notification and reload data when required.

Although, whats more important: do you *really* need to reload data under such harsh requirements? In most cases data reload happens when

1. view controller's `viewDidLoad:` is called
2. it is manually initiated (button, for example)
3. long time passed since the last update was received

Otherwise it's just an overkill.

Comment: Can you clarify on "most cases data reload happens when - long time has passed since the last update was received"? It's true that the reload doesn't have to happen constantly but I certainly don't want someone to click the home button to dismiss the app, reopen the app a day later, and still see the same data.

Comment: Just make a timer that periodically checks the date of the last update. If the data is old (>12h, for example) then trigger reload. Plain and easy. Pulling new data with every sneeze is unacceptable for good UX.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //code to reload table viewdata

}
```

Each time the view appears this method is called. I use this a lot in my app.

Comment: `viewDidAppear:` is not called when user switches items in tab bar or closes and reopens application. Or when full-screen modal view controller is dismissed. Or some other use cases probably, I just can't think of any at the moment. I assume this is the main stumbling block in this question.

Comment: It works for me... I do it all the time. Whenever a tab is switched viewDidAppear is called.

Comment: Yeah, I probably screwed up about tab bar (though I had a problem with it, just don't remember the exact scenario), but, there _are_ cases, when controller goes off screen and doesn't receive `viewDidAppear:` message when coming back. Most common: re-opening application. Less common: dismissing modal view controller, using embedded view controllers.

Comment: Thanks, viewDidAppear definitely works for when tabbing back and forth, so part of the way there!

Comment: @CherylYaeger So where does it fall short?

Comment: When the user clicks the home button and then reopens the app, viewDidAppear does not run.

Comment: @Cheryl I've told you already, that you can't cover all the possible cases in one `viewDidAppear:`. More or less readable and expandable solution is the one I suggested in my answer. You will have your reload-logic code in one handler. All that left is to make sure that notification is sent from where you think reload should happen.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to clarify for @Hackmodford. Thanks again!